# Is there a way to check if user has rated your app?

Tags: ios

I have been extensively searching through Internet but I could not able to come across so far then I have decided to ask the following question in SOF.

My idea is to implement a selling and buying product in my application. There will be no charge from both sides(seller or buyer). However, I only want to receive user feedback to increase my app reputation in the AppStore.

I would like to know how to check whether or not that an app user rate or leave comment for my application in the App Store. I need to know because I want to give him more advertising opportunities within the app.

Sorry again, I wish to provide a sample code but I could not able to come anything to start with.

Comment: Be careful of not violating clause 3.10 in the approval guidelines

Comment: Hi Paulw11, could you please give the link? It is interesting.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Ok I have got it, Paulw11. What do you think from this article? `item 2 Incentivize Users to Review Your App `

Comment: I can't say what Apple will do. If you only care about a review, not whether it is positive or negative you are probably OK. I just wanted you to know that the clause was there

Comment: I see, thanks Paulw11.By the way, Is it possible to access each user comment by writing a script in the itunes- for example Python script ? Because there is only a single URL for each application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to do this.  Most apps just direct people to the app store and then assume they rated the app.  You can have the user copy and past their review into your app and store it so you can double check that they actually did it. That will ensure more people don't try to cheat the system.  Essentially, the more work you make it to unlock the feature, the less likely people are to cheat.

From Apple via @Paulw11's comment:

> Developers who attempt to manipulate or cheat the user reviews or chart ranking in the App Store with fake or paid reviews, or any other inappropriate methods will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata

Comment: Is it possible to access each user comment by writing a script in the appstore- for example Python script ? Because there is only a single URL for each application.

Comment: @texas: iTunes does have an API through which you can get reviews on an  app in JSON form. However, I can't think of any way to identify a user's review. I'd also advise being wary of this whole idea because of Apple's arbitrary censorship -- this sounds like just the kind of thing they'd remove with no opportunity for appeal.

Comment: Yeah, I think it goes against apple's policy to actually gate part of your app until you're sure you got a review.  What I describe above will get you more reviews without making Apple mad.